# array key not accessible once other keys have been accessed

Tags: php, arrays

I feel rather stupid for asking this, but how is it that this

```
       foreach ($fbuser['feed']['data'] as $fbmsg){

            var_dump($fbmsg['message']);
            die;
```

produces the exact result I want, it shows me the contents of the array key 'message'...

...while this throws an error stating that the key 'message' is undefined...

```
       foreach ($fbuser['feed']['data'] as $fbmsg){

           $r .= '<tr><td class="fb_td"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fbmsg['from']['id'].'/picture" class="fb_img"></td><td>'.
                     ' <i>'.$fbmsg['from']['name'].'</i><br>'.
                     $fbmsg['message'].'</td></tr>';
      }
```

Here is the var_dump, clearly containing a ['message'] key...

```
array(19) { ["id"]=> string(28) "167669502405_366091400140059" ["from"]=> array(3) { ["category"]=> string(21) "Professional services" ["name"]=> string(9) "Warp Nine" ["id"]=> string(12) "167669502405" } ["message"]=> string(47) "Nu finns Warp Nine's annons pÃ¥ pizzakartonger!" ["story"]=> string(40) "Warp Nine shared Annonspizza AB's photo." ["story_tags"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(12) "167669502405" ["name"]=> string(9) "Warp Nine" ["offset"]=> int(0) ["length"]=> int(9) ["type"]=> string(4) "page" } } [17]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(15) "182446165166120" ["name"]=> string(14) "Annonspizza AB" ["offset"]=> int(17) ["length"]=> int(14) ["type"]=> string(4) "page" } } } ["picture"]=> string(83) "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/384287_370171156393619_242673100_s.jpg" ["link"]=> string(105) "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=370171156393619&set=a.347118762032192.78549.182446165166120&type=1" ["name"]=> string(15) "Timeline Photos" ["caption"]=> string(88) "Vi har Ã¤ven nÃ¥got att lÃ¤sa dÃ¥ vi Ã¤ter pizzan. SÃ¥hÃ¤r ser kartongen ut pÃ¥ insidan!" ["properties"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(2) "By" ["text"]=> string(14) "Annonspizza AB" ["href"]=> string(71) "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Annonspizza-AB/182446165166120?ref=stream" } } ["icon"]=> string(59) "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif" ["privacy"]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(0) "" } ["type"]=> string(5) "photo" ["status_type"]=> string(12) "shared_story" ["object_id"]=> string(15) "370171156393619" ["application"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(6) "Photos" ["id"]=> string(10) "2305272732" } ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2012-10-04T21:05:55+0000" ["updated_time"]=> string(24) "2012-10-04T21:05:55+0000" ["comments"]=> array(1) { ["count"]=> int(0) } }
```

Comment: your first code snippet only checks the first element in `$fbuser`['feed']['data']`, while the second checks every element.

Comment: yup, realized that. Thanks though. time for bed I guess =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have three arrays inside of `$fbuser['feed']['data']` and array1 has a message key but array2 and array3 do not then you will receive an error.

Try:

```
foreach ($fbuser['feed']['data'] as $fbmsg){
    $r .= '<tr><td class="fb_td"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fbmsg['from']['id'].'/picture" class="fb_img"></td><td>'.
             ' <i>'.$fbmsg['from']['name'].'</i><br>'.
             (isset($fbmsg['message'])?$fbmsg['message']:'').'</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, nevermind - the first 7 keys had it, there was one set in the end that lacked it, which of course made the entire thing crash without even printing the first couple of correct ones. sorry.